# Trying to access property of a class which subclasses a cocoa class gives run-time error

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I made a customized button type(class) that inherits from `NSButton` and has some additional methods as well, but when I try to access the methods that I declared myself, I get a run-time error. Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa

class MCButton: NSButton {
    func testFunc()->Bool {
        return true
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: MCButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if button.testFunc() {   //Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x608000264600)
            button.title = "Hi!"
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I don't have any problems when I only use the methods declared in the superclass(`NSButton`). What's the problem? What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Have you set the appropriate class of the button that you are connecting to the outlet in the interface builder?

Comment: @luk2302 Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "set the appropriate class". Would you explain a little more?

Comment: You probably have a storyboard where you connected the button. What is the class of that button in the interface builder? It **has to be** `MCButton`.

Comment: Wah! Yeah, I hadn't set that! I was being very stupid!

Comment: @luk2302 What do I do with the question now? Should I delete it or would you like to post that as an answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correctly set the button's class in the InterfaceBuilder. It probably has the predefined value set, which is `NSButton`. You have to set it to `MCButton` instead.

Only then you actually get a reference to a correct instance of one of those `MCButton`s.